# Iterator-reducer pattern for functions that may or may not return a value

Tags: c++, c++11

The following function applies a functor on each element and reduces the return value:

```
template <class FCT, class RED>
RED::TYPE forAllElements(FCT functor, RED reducer){
  for(/* all elem in elements */){
    reducer(functor(elem));
  }
  return reducer.value;
}
```

Now, sometimes I might wish to just call the `functor` on all elements, and not reduce anything. Basically, I would then like to have something like:

```
class FunctorThatReturnsNothing{
  void operator() (Elem e){
    // do something, return nothing...
  }
}

class DummyReducer{
  using TYPE = void; // ??? something like that ???

  template <class FCT>
  void operator() (/* ??? what here */){
    // do nothing...
  }
}

forAllElements(FunctorThatReturnsNothing(), DummyReducer());
```

But that won't compile since I have `reducer(functor(elem))` where the non-existent return value of a void function is taken as an argument.

**Is there a way to make it work for void functors without duplicating forAllElements for a `void` and a non-`void` case?**

(For people suspecting an XY-Problem: I basically know different approaches for iterating and reducing and I think that the presented callback approach is appropriate for my case. I just wonder how I can avoid to have duplicate code for the "return value + reducing" and the "just callback" case.)

Comment: So basically you want [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, see the last part of the question, in brackets. I know that I could go that path with iterators, but in the current situation, a callback solution as presented is favorable.

Comment: The cleanest approach would be to `return reducer` instead of `return reducer.value`. Can you refactor your code to use that?

Comment: @filipos: That really seems like a good idea. I will have to check whether it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just make a `VoidReducer` class, but instead of `return reducer.value;` you would need `return reducer.getvalue();`.  Then you simply make `void VoidReducer::getvalue(){}`.

I haven't tested this but the idea should work.  You are allowed to `return f();` if both `f` and the current function have return type `void`.

**EDIT**
Now that I read the question more carefully, I see that the problem you're asking about is the line `reducer(functor(elem));`.
For this I would compile-time dispatch based on `decltype(functor(elem))`.

```
template <class Functor, class Reducer, class Elem>
void Combine(Functor functor, Reducer & reducer, Elem elem, std::true_type)
{
  functor(elem);
}

template <class Functor, class Reducer, class Elem>
void Combine(Functor functor, Reducer & reducer, Elem elem, std::false_type)
{
    reducer(functor(elem));
}

template <class Functor, class Reducer, class Elem>
void Combine(Functor functor, Reducer & reducer, Elem elem)
{
    Combine(functor, reducer, elem, std::is_same<decltype(functor(elem)), void>());
}
```

Then calling `Combine` instead of `reducer(functor(elem))` will correctly reduce the return value of `functor` if and only if it's not void.

PS: Sprinkle references and `std::forward` calls to taste.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use your `forAllElements` function instead if using `std::for_each` directly you can create an overload of the function that doesn't take a reducer, and simply uses `std::for_each` internally:

```
template <class FCT>
void forAllElements(FCT functor){
    std::for_each(std::begin(...), std::end(...), functor);
}

...

forAllElements(FunctorThatReturnsNothing());
```

If it's not possible to get "iterators" for your container (if you use a non-standard container or pointers), you can of course have your own loop and just simply call `functor`.

Answer (score 0):

A clean and flexible approach is to return the function object itself, instead of a hardcoded `value` field.

```
template <class FCT, class RED>
RED forAllElements(FCT functor, RED reducer){
  for(/* all elem in elements */){
    reducer(functor(elem));
  }
  return reducer;
}
```

The operation can then have no return value, or even more than one return value, with informative names.

Your original method can be seen as a convenience wrapper over this primitive component:

```
template <class FCT, class RED>
RED::TYPE forAllElements_convenience(FCT functor, RED reducer){
  return forAllElements(functor, reducer).value;
}
```